# Unify capture groups for multiple cases in regex

Tags: regex

Suppose that I have the following requirements for my regex;

- Match anything between `cached` and `is` (`cached 1a23a is` ⇒ `1a23a`)
- Match anything between `forwarded` and `to` (`forwarded 2ab34 to` ⇒ `2ab34`)
- Match anything between `replied` and `by` (`replied klaskd by` ⇒ `klaskd`)

*Note that the pairing is important, e.g. capturing a string between `cached` and `to` is not OK.*

Currently, I am using the following regex;

```
(?:cached (.*?) is|forwarded (.*?) to|replied (.*?) by)
```

But this is producing **three capture groups**. Is it possible to write a regex that captures within a single group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following regex, you can match what you are requiring, within a single capture group;

```
(?:cached(?= .* is)|forwarded(?= .* to)|replied(?= .* by)) (.*) (?:is|to|by)
```

Just adding positive lookahead for starting boundary words did the trick.

To see it in action, [here](https://regex101.com/r/l97uW3/5)